# Execute function(s) if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing an extension script powered by tampermonkey (or greasemonkey). I've got some functions and I've appended checkbox which, if checked, would trigger the certain function. Now, if I check it once, I'd like it to be checked forever, until I uncheck it manually.

I've tried binding it on the homepage header (so it's there through whole website), but once the page is refreshed/reloaded, I'd need to check it again, so it would run. I've also tried binding it to another page, but in order to run, I'd got to click on that page, check it, and then it would run only once. Here is part of the code that should trigger the function(s):

```
$('<div>').addClass('class123').append(
    $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'cbox1'
}).change(function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    myFunc();
}
});
),
```

Here is an example of one of the functions:

```
myFunc(){
    if($('#id:contains("You are welcome!")').length > 0{
        window.location.href = "some.url";
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = "some.other.url";
    }
}
```

As I said, I'd like it to autorun once I checked until I uncheck it manually. The function(s) are being consisted with few basic parameters (manipulating script to jump from page to page within the same website domain.

So, how to make script check whether or not appended checkbox element is checked, and, if it is, to execute functions with repetition, only if the condition inside the function is satisfied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note, if you already have a reference to an Element, do not do `$(this).is(":checked")`.  Simply do `this.checked` to get the boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

The `.is(':checked')` is only **evaluated at runtime**, so if your checkbox is not checked when the script is executed, then it will never fire. What you need is to **bind an event handler** to your checkbox element, so that it will be fired whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log('Checked: ' + this.checked);
}

const $div = $('<div>').addClass('class123').append(
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'cbox1'
  }).on('change', myFunc)
);

$div.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is also a syntax error with your code, where you are missing a closing `)`. It is unclear if you meant to select a `<div>` or create a new `<div>` in your code, but I assume you know what you're doing.

`$('<div>')` actually **creates a new element** without appending it to the DOM. So, if you meant to **select** a pre-existing `<div>`, just use `$('div')` instead. You can use the same approach as above, or listen to event bubbling:

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log('Checked: ' + this.checked);
}

$('div').addClass('class123').append(
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'cbox1'
  })
);

$('div').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', myFunc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I'm creating a div, so I guess $('<div>') should be OK. There is also whole lot of code up and down, but I took just the elements that are dependent with the original question. Thanks for the notes and help, will try it soon.
PS: As of syntax error, I chopped the part of the code, and yes, it's functional. I will edit it.